# Overleaf ignoring Pisymbol command

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, pifont

I'm attempting to draw a dancing man in the label of a node of my drawing, but Overleaf is straight up ignoring my `Pisymbol`. The text "dancing fellow" is displayed correctly, but the symbol is not. Do I need to include something in particular along with pifont?

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 1.2) node [label = below : Dancing fellow \Pisymbol{dancers}{181}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried the command outside of the tikz environment and it is still not dispaying the dancing guy.

The symbol was found [here](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf) on page 226.
Thanks in advance to anyone.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Note there's a `{}` missing before the `;`, as it stands you get an error (which is unrelated to your actual problem).

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no LaTeX support for the `dancers` font and the Comprehensive List should be clearer about this.

```latex
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{dancers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dancers}{m}{n}{<-> dancers}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 1.2) node [label = below : Dancing fellow \Pisymbol{dancers}{181}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: But in the Table 531: dancers Dancing Men pag. 211 there is a package named: `dancers`. But does this package works? http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf. Is it no good for overleaf?

Comment: what a pity that this symbol blurs when scale 3 times.